# How to change multiple lines with vim?

Tags: vim

For example, my source is:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>111</td>
```

I want to change `td` to `th`, I use `ctrl + v` to focus the `d` column, what to do next?

## Notice

I don't want to use `:%s/td/th/g`. Just want to try `ctrl + v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate on the visual selection by typing ":"

e.g. (after visual selection) :s/d/h/

More info at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection

Answer (score 7):

Once you have the h column highlighted and since you only want to replace the d with h do this: Press the 'r' key for replace and then press the 'h' key which is what you want to use instead.

Answer (score 2):

1. Visually select the lines:

   ```
   vjj
   ```
2. Perform the substitution (the visual range, `'<,'>`, is automatically inserted by Vim after you pressed `:`):

   ```
   :'<,'>s/td/th/g
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically want to use visual block, just do `rh` after you have selected the column using ctrl+v and a movement. If you want to change the 'd' to multiple letters, do `s<letters><esc>`

Answer (score 1):

The Tim Pope's [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin can be very handy in these type of situations. To change a surrounding tag you do the following:

<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>s</kbd>
<kbd>t</kbd>
<kbd><</kbd>
<kbd>t</kbd>
<kbd>h</kbd>
<kbd>></kbd>
<kbd>return</kbd>

You can no use the `.` command to repeat this (assuming you have [reapeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) installed) or use a macro. e.g. `qqcst<th>^M^Mq100@q`. However I find that selecting the lines with `V` and using the `:normal` command to be the best way:

```
:norm cst<th>
```

Note: if you use a visual selection the `'<,'>` range will be put in when you press `:`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use builtin techniques, but just so you know, there is a great plugin called [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) that I would use to do this (if not just :s).  It is meant to mimic Sublime Text's multiple cursor feature, allowing you to replace or edit many sections of the code at once.  I'd check it out.  Comes in handy.  Would be especially valuable in this case if you had "d"s inside the tags or even "td"s; or worst case, you only wanted to replace the top line and the bottom line with th (probably not in this example, but you can easily imagine the situation, and `:[range]s/<pattern>/<replace>/gc` is REALLY tedious....and in my opinion easy to screw up.